# Find records which have certain value in their array column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have a recipes table and an ingredients table.
In the recipes table there is an ingredient column that is an array listing the ids of all the ingredients necessary for each recipe.

I want to search through that array to find if it contains one particular ingredient.

I found the `include?` method which works great in a case like :

```
Recipe.find(35).ingredient.include? params[:ingredient]
```

I'm trying to make that work with a where method to get something like this :

```
Recipe.where('ingredient.include?', params[:ingredient].to_i)
```

It seems pretty straightforward but it doesn't work. I tried removing the comma, same result.

I can't figure out the proper syntax for it to work.

Comment: damn, my insta-dup-hammer didn't work because this wasn't tagged ruby-on-rails :(

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up, keeping a column with an array of ids is generally not the best solution!

The preferred approach is Rail's [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association, which uses a join table (ala `ingredients_recipes`) to store the relation.

Storing ids in an array is a non-starter in many databases, as it simply isn't supported. It's possible in Postgres using the `@>` contains operator, but you lose the benefits of relational integrity (foreign key constraints) as well as sacrificing automatic management by Rails and other ORMs.

It's an open architectural question though; if you're dealing with high-volume data (millions of rows), arrays could potentially have performance benefits (see [Using postgres arrays in relations](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/363)).  It usually isn't worth the hassle of giving up Rails' automatic management of the association though!

Comment: it's not a string column.

Comment: Right you are, I didn't notice the postgresql tag. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!So @gmcnaughton is it ok to have a column with an array of integer or do you still think I should havea join table (I did hesitate between the two options)

Comment: I initially made the same misstake when reading the question - you could still salvage this answer with an edit as its basically a good answer and does not deserve downvotes.

Comment: @MarineBe I would still recommend the join table approach over arrays, mostly to make your life easier! For instance, Rails will understand and manage the join table records for you.  But it looks like this is an open architectural question with postgres (see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11853/should-arrays-of-ids-stored-in-postgres-use-varchar-int-or-another-type for instance)

Comment: @gmcnaughton there are so many valid reasons why you might want to store an array of ids. So many, in fact, that the good folks who hack on Postgres provided us with an **array column type**. You'll note that in the documentation for the **postgres array column type** that it doesn't say anywhere not to use it.

Comment: Everybody's stackoverflow experience will be much more efficient if you save preaching for comments (like I'm doing!) and save **answers** for **actual answers** for the **actual question**.

Comment: @MichaelJohnston thanks for the feedback! I agree that stackoverflow is intended for answers, not coaching. http://wiki.c2.com/?MuAnswer

Answer (score 0):

You would query an array by using `any`:

```
Recipe.where('WHERE ? = ANY (ingredient)', params[:ingredient])
```

Using an array here is hardly ideal though. There are cases where a simple array is suited but not when you should be using a proper relationship.

```
class Recipe
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, though: :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end

class Ingredient
  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, though: :recipe_ingredients
end
```

This will let you query from both ends:

```
Recipe.joins(:ingredients)
      .where(ingredients: { name: ['basil', 'thyme'] } )
Ingredient.joins(:recipes)
      .where(recipes: { main_type: 'dessert' } )
```

As well as attach data to the `recipe_ingredients` table such as the quantity (which is not possible with `has_and_belongs_to_many`) - it will also let you query the join table directly which can be very useful.

### Why not use an array?

Because `ActiveRecord` is not built around using arrays to store associations. You basically lose all the benefits of ActiveRecord associations for little or no performance benefits. You cannot use foreign key constraints to ensure data integrity in the DB either.

Comment: To search for a value in an array in Postgres you would do `SELECT * FROM recipies WHERE 1 = ANY (ingredient);` - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html

Comment: Using a proper join table with a compound index on the foreign key columns might actually be more performant than doing array searches.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @max. I did try to do a join table but I couldn't figure out how to send data from my form to the two tables since some of the data belonged in the Recipe table and some ine the RecipeIngredient. That's why I gave up and went with the array. Any advice or useful link on that ?

Comment: My advice is to ask a new question and include an example of what you tried to do and what the problem is.

Comment: Otherwise it just leads to an unending number of comments.

Comment: Yes sir ! Will do.

Comment: here's three reasons when you would use an array to store ids: 1.) they're ids from a different database, and there is not a one-to-one mapping between the part of your model that is populated from data from the other model. 2.) You're developing an mvp and don't want to pay the db cost of fully modelled relationships until you actually develop the features that use them 3.) You need the relationships only for possible future auditing. Anyone who says "**never** use an array" just hasn't worked on enough apps.

Comment: I'm not saying never. I'm saying that arrays are not a suitible replacement for decent relational database design like the 99% of cases when noobs try to create many to many associations with them.